# How to create custom controls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Which is the best way to create custom controls in a Big Mvc application?         Partials views which  means a partial view for each control ? HTML Helpers? another alternative?

please find below a sample of custom control that I have in the asp web application:

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("<div class=\"btnContainer\">");

        base.Render(writer);


        writer.WriteLine("</div>");

        writer.WriteLine("<div class=\"clr\"></div>");
    }
```

Comment: Is "big" relevant? What do you mean by "custom control"? What have you tried?

Comment: custom control like ascx control in asp webforms.I mean by big I have about 50 usercontrol to create .I didnt tried yet I am still researching the best way.

Comment: If you're researching the best way, you must have a list of requirements. Compare the possibilities you find to that list and you'll have your best candidate.

Comment: really depends on what kind of control you're trying to create.   you should give us an example of one of your ascx controls

Comment: thanks jamie.I edited my question and I posted a code of a custom control that I have in my web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partials alone aren't really "controls". They need something to drive them. In MVC 5 and previous you can use child actions to create something very similar to an ASCX control. In MVC 6+ View Components are the way to go.

You can also use an `HtmlHelper` extension. Really, the chief determination of which you should use boils down to whether you need external data access. If you need to query a database, hit a Web API, etc., then use child actions / view components. If you're self contained (i.e. you just want to render a bit of HTML based on some existing value you already have, then you can go with an `HtmlHelper` extension. However, a child action / view component still works in this scenario, as well, meaning they're much more versatile overall.